# Euler's derivation of Lemniscate addition theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

In the notes ["a Brief history of elliptic integral addition theorems"](https://math.osu.edu/sites/math.osu.edu/files/glasscock_ellipticintegral_2016.pdf), the author states at the very beginning of Chapter 4 that Euler found a general solution of the equation
$$
\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}=\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^4}}\tag{1}
$$
to be

$$
x=\frac{c\sqrt{1-y^4}+y\sqrt{1-c^4}}{1+x^2c^2}\tag{2}
$$

I don't have a problem proving that this is a solution, but how could Euler have possibly **arrived** at such solution?

Answer (score 4):

The following comments are summarized from Sec2 Chapter 1 in Topic In Complex Function Theory Vol.1. (By C.L. Siegel; translated by A. Shenitzer and D. Solitar) by my own understanding. In fact, at the begining of this section, named *The Euler addition theorem*, the author states that "In this section we shall attempt to reconstruct Euler's train of thought".

---

It may date back to Fagnano, who attempted to rationalize the following integrand, which now is referred to as the lemniscatic integral,
\begin{equation}
 s=s(r)=\int_{0}^{r} \frac{{\rm d}r}{\sqrt{1-r^4}}.
\end{equation}
It is well-known that an analogous formula for the arc of a circle
\begin{equation}\label{eq-2}
 \arcsin r=\int_{0}^{r} 
 \frac{{\rm d} r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
can be rationalized by taking the follow substitution
$$r=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}, \qquad (0\leq t\leq 1.)$$

Now in the above lemniscatic integral we have $\sqrt{1-r^4}$ instead of $\sqrt{1-r^2}$. This suggests the use of the analogous substitution
$$r^2=\frac{2t^2}{1+t^4}, \qquad (0\leq t\leq 1.)$$
Then one can obtain
\begin{equation}
 \int_{0}^{r} \frac{d r}{\sqrt{1-r^{4}}}=\sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{d t}{\sqrt{1+t^{4}}}, \quad  \quad(0 \leq r \leq 1) \tag{2} \label{eq-1}
\end{equation}

If we treat the right-hand of of the above  integrand in an analogous manner by using the substitution
$$t^{2}=\frac{2 u^{2}}{1-u^{4}},$$
then we can get that
$$\int_{0}^{t} \frac{d t}{\sqrt{1+t^{4}}}=\sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{u} \frac{d u}{\sqrt{1-u^{4}}}.$$
In view of \eqref{eq-1}, we now have the doubling of a lemniscatic arc, that is,
$$\int_{0}^{r} \frac{d r}{\sqrt{1-r^{4}}}=2 \int_{0}^{u} \frac{d u}{\sqrt{1-u^{4}}},$$
where
$$r^{2}=\frac{4 u^{2}\left(1-u^{4}\right)}{(1+u^{4})^{2}}, \qquad (0\leq u \leq 1).$$

Now we go back to \eqref{eq-2}. In fact,the doubling of a circular arc states that
$$\int_{0}^{r} \frac{{\rm d} r}{\sqrt{1-r^{2}}}=2 \int_{0}^{u} \frac{{\rm d} u}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}},$$
where
$$r=2u \sqrt{1-u^2}.$$
This result can be obtained by using the transcendental substitution
$u=\sin x$. This result includes the relation
$$\sin (2x)=2\sin x \cos x,$$
which is a special case of the trigonometric addition theorem:
$$\sin(x+y)=\sin x \cos y +\sin y \cos x.$$
The latter can be obtained by means of the substitutions
$$u=\sin x, \quad v=\sin y, \quad u \sqrt{1-v^{2}}+v \sqrt{1-u^{2}}=\sin (x+y),$$
and the formation of inverse functions and takes the form
$$\int_{0}^{u} \frac{{\rm d} u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}+\int_{0}^{v} \frac{{\rm d} v}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}=\int_{0}^{r} \frac{{\rm d} r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}, \quad r=u \sqrt{1-v^{2}}+v \sqrt{1-u^{2}}. \tag{4}\label{eq-4}$$
If we view $v$ as constant, then  the above equality  suggests that
$r=u \sqrt{1-v^{2}}+v \sqrt{1-u^{2}}$ is a general solution of
$$\frac{{\rm du}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\frac{{\rm d}r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}.$$
Note that \eqref{eq-4} is obtained by replacing $r=2 u \sqrt{1-u^2}$ by  $r=u \sqrt{1-v^{2}}+v \sqrt{1-u^{2}}$.
Recall that the substitution, which gives us the doubling of lemniscatic arc,
$$r=\frac{2u \sqrt{1-u^4}}{1+u^4}.$$
It is plausible to replace  the numerator $2u \sqrt{1-u^4}$ to $u\sqrt{1-v^4}+v\sqrt{1-u^2}$. As denominator we choose the simplest symmetric function of $u$ and $v$ which becomes $1+u^4$ for $u=v$, namely, $1+u^2 v^2$. We thus arrive at the substitution
$$r=\frac{u\sqrt{1-v^4}+v\sqrt{1-u^2}}{1+u^2 v^2}.$$
Taking this substitution, it  can be proved that
$$\int_{0}^{r}\frac{{\rm d}r}{\sqrt{1-r^4}}=\int_{0}^{u}\frac{{\rm d}u}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}+\int_{0}^{v}\frac{{\rm d}v}{\sqrt{1-v^4}}.$$
Then one obtains, by viewing $v$ as constant, that
$$r=\frac{u\sqrt{1-v^4}+v\sqrt{1-u^2}}{1+u^2 v^2}$$
is a general solution of
$$\frac{{\rm d} u}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}=\frac{{\rm d} r}{\sqrt{1-r^4}}.$$